# How do a put binary data into postgres through HDBC?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, hdbc

I have a Haskell application that, as one of many steps, needs to store and retrieve raw binary blob data in a database.  I'm not completely above deciding to, instead, store that data in plain disk files, but that does start leading to an additional round of permissions issues, so right now I want to go with the database.

I've created a table with a column of type `bytea`.

I have a Lazy Bytestring in memory.

When I make a call like this

```
run conn "INSERT INTO documents VALUES (?)" [toSql $ rawData mydoc]
```

postgres gets a bit angry at the data.  The exact error message is

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0xcf72
```

I also know beyond doubt that I have NUL values in the data stream.  So, with all of that in mind, what is the correct way to encode the data safely for insertion?

---

Updated

Here is the description for my table

```
db=> \d+ documents
                          Table "public.documents"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id              | character varying(16)       | not null  | extended | 
 importtime      | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    | 
 filename        | character varying(255)      | not null  | extended | 
 data            | bytea                       | not null  | extended | 
 recordcount     | integer                     | not null  | plain    | 
 parsesuccessful | boolean                     | not null  | plain    | 
Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

This is the full text of a module that demonstrates the current problem I'm having after adding jamsdidh's code.  My error message has changed from the encoding problem above to "invalid input syntax for type bytea".

```
module DBMTest where

import qualified Data.Time.Clock as Clock
import Database.HDBC.PostgreSQL
import Database.HDBC
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import Data.ByteString hiding (map)
import Data.Char
import Data.Word8
import Numeric

exampleData = pack ([0..65536] :: [Word8]) :: ByteString

safeEncode :: ByteString -> ByteString
safeEncode x = pack (convert' =<< unpack x)
    where
    convert' :: Word8 -> [Word8]
    convert' 92 = [92, 92]
    convert' x | x >= 32 && x < 128 = [x]
    convert' x = 92:map c2w (showIntAtBase 8 intToDigit x "")

runTest = do
    conn <- connectPostgreSQL "dbname=db"
    t <- Clock.getCurrentTime
    withTransaction conn
        (\conn -> run conn
            "INSERT INTO documents (id, importTime, filename, data, recordCount, parseSuccessful) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            [toSql (15 :: Int),
             toSql t,
             toSql ("Demonstration data" :: String),
             toSql $ safeEncode exampleData,
             toSql (15 :: Int),
             toSql (True :: Bool)])
```

Comment: I've never used HDBC, but I have had success with postgresql-simple?    (I haven't tried it for bytea data though.)

Comment: So far, no.  I have quite a lot of code already and already have a handle on this API.  I cannot afford the cost of switching right now.

Comment: Turn query-logging on at the PostgreSQL end and see how the data is being escaped. It should be octal (older format) or hex (newer format). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5318

Comment: Are you using HDBC-postgresql or HDBC-odbc? I'd recommend you try HDBC-odbc to play with postgresql, since the bindings are more developed (and faster).

Comment: I believe this is an issue in postgresql-simple as well. At least I'm getting the same error with what I believe is essentially the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive this is a bug in HDBC-postgresql.  I can explain why I think this is so, and can give you a workaround that I put together and tested.

---

I would expect HDBC-postgresql to convert a bytestring to the appropriate format to be inserted, but you can quickly verify that it is instead expecting the bytestring to hold the octal-backspace-escaped values of the data.  For instance,

```
run conn "INSERT INTO documents VALUES (?)" [toSql $ B.pack [92, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31]]
```

inserts the single character 'A' into the database!  This only makes sense when you realize that [92, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31] is the ascii representation of "\101", and "\101" is the octal representation of 'A'.  Because the octal-backspace-escaped strings guarantee allowing values in the range 32-127 to be passed directly through (see the link Richard Huxton supplied in the comments for the details), the insert query *does* in fact work properly for standard english text, and could have gone unnoticed....

```
run conn "INSERT INTO documents VALUES (?)" [toSql $ B.pack [65]]
```

also inserts 'A'.  Values higher than 127 aren't guaranteed to work, and are interpreted based on the character encoding used.  If you look at the HDBC-postgresql code, or the logs of a query, you can see that it is setting the variable 'client_encoding' to utf8.  The data coming in from the bytestring is therefore expected to be valid utf8, and complains when it sees a sequence that could not exist as a utf8 character.

The proper fix would be to wait for the bug to be fixed by the HDBC-postgresql guys, but in the meantime, you can use this code as a workaround....

```
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import Data.Char
import Data.Word8
import Numeric
import Text.Printf

convert::B.ByteString->B.ByteString
convert x = B.pack (convert' =<< B.unpack x)
          where
            convert'::Word8->[Word8]
            convert' 92 = [92, 92]
            convert' x | x >= 32 && x < 128 = [x]
            convert' x = 92:map c2w (printf "%03o" x)
```

Now you can just use

```
run conn "INSERT INTO documents VALUES (?)" [toSql $ convert $ rawData mydoc]
```

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to hdbc-postgresql, if I am wrong about this being a bug, they will set me straight soon!  See https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-postgresql/issues/33

Comment: I've implemented this with the difference that my ByteString is a Lazy bytestring.  Now I just get postgres telling me that I'm giving an invalid input syntax for type bytea.  There is no additional information in the query log, even though I have logging set to 'all'.  Although I also have logging set to syslog, so maybe it sends less data in that case.

Comment: @SavanniD'Gerinel- Can you get it work with strict bytestrings?  It will be easier to debug if I know this....

Comment: No, I can't.  I added a big swath of example code that illustrates what I am doing.  If you like, I can also add library versions.

Comment: @SavanniD'Gerinel- I had a bug in my code, and fixed it.... `showIntAtBase 8 intToDigit x ""` doesn't add leading zeros, so bytes lower than 32 were broken (remember, 32-127 was just passed through anyway).  Also, in your example you used `[1..65536]::[Word8]`.  This doesn't do what you think it will.  Remember, `Word8` only goes from 0-255, and strangly Haskell just truncates conversions from numbers greater than 255 rather than complain, so `([0..65536]::[Word8]) = ([0..0]::[Word8]) = [0]`.  If you want to test the full range of chars, use `[0..255]::[Word8]`

Comment: I have the code appearing to work now (though I don't have my my retrieval operation working to verify it).  I modified your code slightly to have a minimal set of modules and explicit namespaces, since I had a lot of trouble finding c2w.